# How to use $(this) to dynamically retrieve the title attribute of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop an friend-tag system for my website.

I have an anchor tag surrounding my div tag which has an title to it. i am trying to use the following codes to retrieve the title from it but the result is always undefined.

```
<a href="#" class="add-link" onclick="addFunc()" title="test1">
    <div class="divclass">
        blabla    
    </div>
</a>
```

```js
function addFunc(){
    var username = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#content').html(username);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0f4mun8r/3/

any idea why?

thanks!

Comment: $(this) is jquery object. Here you are using Javascript function.

Comment: `this` is broken in onclick event attributes which use really funky (and broken) scoping - here you go http://jsfiddle.net/d130j1eh/ . I suggest you look into better, more sane click binding like `addEventListener` (why do you need jQuery here anyway?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include jquery in your fiddle. Also if you use jquery bind your events with it like this:

```
$(".add-link").on("click", function addFunc(){
    var username = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#content').html(username);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0f4mun8r/4/

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems.

---

First:

You have configured JS Fiddle to wrap all your code in an onload handler. This stops the function being a global so when you call `addFunc` it can't be found.

---

Second:

You are calling jQuery but haven't included the jQuery library.

---

Third:

The value of `this` depends on how you call the function.

When the `onclick` function is called, `this` is the element.

When `addFunc` is called (if you fix the other problems), since you haven't specified a context, `this` is `window` (the default object).

---

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript.

```
jQuery(".add-link").on('click', addFunc);
```

And if you use jQuery, then [include the library](http://jquery.com/download/) in your page.

Comment: Also, the fiddle doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: For my own benefit, is there any difference between `JQuery('.add-link').on('click', func)` and `JQuery('.add-link').click(fund)`?

Comment: From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/): *This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`*

Comment: thank you for the response! pretty new to web development and this is informative for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to call it with class name :

```
$('.add-link').click(function() {
    var username = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(username);
    $('#content').html(username);
});
```